# Nikah between a Sunni girl and Shia boy

Tags: nikah, shia-sunni

Assalam u alaikum brothers and sisters... I need your help regarding the sunni shia marriage. Can a sunni girl marry shia? Because no matter what we are, we are all Muslims, so please guide me whether a sunni can marry a shia person?

Comment: Like you said, of course they can since both of them are Muslim. Heck, one can argue that religion doesn't even come into play if two people want to get married but that's a different discussion. Any opinion or "fact" stating otherwise is most likely due to differences in culture and tradition.

Comment: As far as I can remember, it is permissible from the viewpoint of Shia that ""a Shia boy get married to a Sunni girl" (For more answers, you'd better to refer to the mentioned link as above. Good luck.